# How to use order by(Sorting) on Secondary index using Cassandra DB

Tags: cassandra

My table schema is:

```
CREATE TABLE users
(user_id BIGINT PRIMARY KEY, 
user_name text, 
email_ text);
```

I inserted below rows into the table.

```
INSERT INTO users(user_id, email_, user_name)
VALUES(1, 'abc@test.com', 'ABC');

INSERT INTO users(user_id, email_, user_name)
VALUES(2, 'abc@test.com', 'ZYX ABC');

INSERT INTO users(user_id, email_, user_name)
VALUES(3, 'abc@test.com', 'Test ABC');

INSERT INTO users(user_id, email_, user_name)
VALUES(4, 'abc@test.com', 'C ABC');
```

For searching data into the `user_name` column, I created an index to use the `LIKE` operator with `'%%'`:

```
CREATE CUSTOM INDEX  idx_users_user_name ON users (user_name)
USING 'org.apache.cassandra.index.sasi.SASIIndex'
WITH OPTIONS = {
'mode': 'CONTAINS',
'analyzer_class': 'org.apache.cassandra.index.sasi.analyzer.NonTokenizingAnalyzer', 
'case_sensitive': 'false'};
```

Problem:1
When I am executing below Query, it returns 3 records only, instead of 4.

```
select * 
from users 
where user_name like '%ABC%';
```

Problem:2
When I use below query, it gives an error as

```
ERROR: com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.InvalidQueryException: 
ORDER BY with 2ndary indexes is not supported. 
Query =select * from users where user_name like '%ABC%' ORDER BY user_name ASC;
```

Query:

```
select * 
from users 
where user_name like '%ABC%' 
ORDER BY user_name ASC;
```

My requirement is to filter the `user_name` with `order by user_name`.

Answer (score 1):

The first query does work correctly for me using `cassandra:latest` which is now `cassandra:3.11.3`. You might want to double-check the inserted data (or just recreate from scratch using the cql statements you provided).

The second one gives you enough info - ordering by secondary indexes is not possible in Cassandra. You might have to sort the result set in your application.

That being said I would **not** recommend running this setup in real apps. With some additional scale (when you have many records) this will be a suicide performance-wise. I should not go into much detail since maybe you already understand this and SO is not a wikia/documentation site, so here is a [link](https://docs.datastax.com/en/cql/3.3/cql/cql_using/useWhenIndex.html).

Comment: yes, exactly. in real time i can not short the data by application because of performance issue, while having large number of rows in a filter.
Thanks @Nestor Sokil